# How to read lines from a C script from Java's BufferedReader?

Tags: java, linux, bufferedreader

I'm running this java program on a raspberry pi. The program is supposed to run the script "hello_pixy" and scan what it prints out. When I run hello_pixy manually, it prints out lines normally (Via C's printf line). But when I run the program, nothing is printed out and the BufferedReader didn't read any lines.

If I substitute the script for something like "ls", then the BufferedReader reads it and prints it out. Is there a way I can change the "printf"s in C to send to the InputStream (I don't really know C, just enough from Java experience)?

```
    Process process = null;

    try {
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sudo .ss/pixy/build/hello_pixy/hello_pixy");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } //for Windows

    try {
        process.waitFor();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
    String line;

    String print = "";
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            print += line;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("\nCodescan:\n\n" + print);
```

The code I'm executing is here: https://github.com/De-etz/pixy/blob/master/src/host/hello_pixy/hello_pixy.cpp

Comment: Nothing to do with C, especially given it is not a "script" but a compiled binary.

Comment: why are you trying to read from input stream? probably you need output stream

Comment: @IlyaBursov the `InputStream` of a process is its stdout.

Comment: Some notes: running `sudo` probably means the process is waiting for a process. And you can't read the process's stdout after you have already waited for it to finish. You need to first read, and then `waitFor`.

Comment: @RealSkeptic InputStream is used to read data, how can it be stdout? We often don't read from stdout but instead write to it. Did you mean that the `stdout` from C is directed to `InputStream`, like piped one programs output to another as input?

Comment: @ManjinderSinghHanjra in this case we are communicating with a process, and we want to read (InputStream) what that process writes (to stdout). From the point of view of the program running in the process, it is writing to stdout. From the point of view of the Java program, we are reading from an input stream.

Comment: Ok. So, it's piping one process's output to another as input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing this back to front. You must read all the process's output *first*, and *then* call `waitFor()`. Your way you will probably just deadlock, as the process can't exit until it has produced all its output, and if you're not reading it, it will eventually block.

Notes:

1. C is not a scripting language, and a compiled program is not a script by definition.
2. Code that depends on the success of code in a prior `try` block must be inside that `try` block. At present you are continuing after exceptions as though they didn't happen. Don't write code like this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and tips. At first it didn't work but I realized my path wasn't correct either. Once I made both fixes it worked, thanks.